# For loop compilation error in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a data frame in R that lists monthly sales data by department for a store. Each record contains a month/year, a department name, and the total sales in that department for the month. I'm trying to calculate the mean sales by department, adding them to the vector `avgs` but I seem to be having two problems: the total sales per department is not compiling at all (its evaluating to zero) and `avgs` is compiling by record instead of by department. Here's what I have:

```
avgs = c()
for(dept in data$departmentName){
  total <- 0
  for(record in data){
    if(identical(data$departmentName, dept)){
      total <- total + data$ownerSales[record]
    }
  }
  avgs <- c(avgs, total/72)
}
```

Upon looking at `avgs` on completion of the loop, I find that it's returning a vector of zeroes the length of the data frame rather than a vector of 22 averages (there are 22 departments). I've been tweaking this forever and I'm sure it's a stupid mistake, but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: R is not a compiled language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use `library(dplyr)`?:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% # or dept
    summarise(total_plength = sum(Petal.Length), # total owner sales
              weird_divby72 = total_plength/72) # total/72?
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     Species total_plength weird_divby72
      <fctr>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1     setosa          73.1      1.015278
2 versicolor         213.0      2.958333
3  virginica         277.6      3.855556
```

your case would probably look like this :

```
data %>% group_by(deptName) %>%
    summarise(total_sales = sum(ownerSales),
              monthly_sales = total_sales/72)
```

I like `dplyr` for it's syntax and pipeability. I think it is a huge improvement over base R for ease of data wrangling. Here is a good cheat sheet to help you get rolling: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Haha, didn't realize I didn't explain the division. There are 72 months in the data set, so I was going for total sales / 72 = average. I'm pretty novice in R and have never seen `dplyr`, in this example `Species` would be equivalent to my `departmentName`? And the resulting columns would give me my `dept`, `total`, and `avg`?